# Nodejs Excel file with graph and VB module

Tags: node.js, excel, plot, vba

I am working on a project that I need to make an excel file in nodejs and then send the file to the client side. However, I need to have possibility to not only insert some data in the workbook but also possibilities to plot the data. I am also interested if it is possible to write some VB code directly in nodejs to such excel file. Is there any package to do this for me?
Thanks

Comment: what have you tried doing so far?

Comment: Nothing yet. Just trying to find from net and meanwhile asking here what package is suitable for such work

Comment: I did not find something that I can user VBA too but at the end I will use xlsx-workbook and xlsx-chart npms